# Only Administrator user can execute some commands

Tags: permissions

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS edition 32 bit and Now these days I am working on Ubuntu Customization. My customization OS having 2 users as follows:

1. Administrator with full permission.
2. Net user(Standard User) with limited permission.

Now I am installing some external packages and commands and now i want that my Net user couldn't access them.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the POSIX systems, there are 3 modes of accessing a file: owner **U**ser, **G**roup and **O**thers with 3 types of permissions: **R**ead/**W**rite/e**X**ecute. There is a bitmask for each file on system which contains those permissions. [Read more…](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)

The basic idea is to put Net User to `others` and deny others Read/Write/Execute the particular file. This is done by

```bsh
sudo chmod 750 /path/to/file_or_directory
```

Initially, the `others` is the group where each new user appears. So if you want to deny them from accessing Bash, you have to write

```bsh
sudo chmod 750 /bin/bash
```

This will set permissions to `rwxr-x---`. To allow access again, use

```bsh
sudo chmod 755 /bin/bash
```